# Discord Python - ffmpeg not Found

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord

So I am making a music bot for Discord and I need ffmpeg for it. So I have Installed it and Placed in C: and also added to the Environment Variables. But whenever I run the Code I get the Error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

I do not have Any Idea why this doesn't Work.

https://prnt.sc/v4in62 <-- This is How I add Environment Variables

Comment: try using pip install ffmpeg

Comment: However thats not the issue here , its not a ModuleNotFound Error.